# How to feed tensorflow an image from a url?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

The five lines commented out below should work but do not . The prediction score is not anywhere close to what I would expect and when I do plt.imshow(img) it shows the wrong image. Here is the link to my [notebook in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QRFZ95giZ0igmMgE6NPs-yhSPjwTAxxS?usp=sharing).

```
x, y = next(valid_generator)
image = x[0, :, :, :]
true_index = np.argmax(y[0])
plt.imshow(image)

image_url = 'https://mysite_example/share/court3.jpg'
image_url = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Court', origin=image_url )

#img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img( image_url, target_size=( 224, 224 ) )
#img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
#img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) 
#prediction_scores = model.predict(np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0))
#plt.imshow(img)

# Expand the validation image to (1, 224, 224, 3) before predicting the label
prediction_scores = model.predict(np.expand_dims(image, axis=0))
predicted_index = np.argmax(prediction_scores)
print("True label: " + get_class_string_from_index(true_index))
print("Predicted label: " + get_class_string_from_index(predicted_index)
```

Comment: u need to download the file with some code first, i guess it's the only way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `tf.keras.utils.get_file` downloads the file from url to  local cache only if the file is not already cached. So if you are using the same cache name for all the urls ("Court" in your code ?) the you will see only the first file.

Also while training you have a preprocess step of normalizing all the pixels by dividing them with `255`. You have to apply the same preprocessing step during inference also.

Working Code:

```
_, axis = plt.subplots(1,3) 

for i, image_url in enumerate(['https://squashvideo.site/share/court3.jpg',
                               'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0f/c2/9b/0fc29b35532f8e2fb998f5605212ab27.jpg',
                               'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/squash-court-photo-empty-30346175.jpg']):  
  image_url = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Court', origin=image_url )
  img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_url, target_size=( 224, 224 ) )
  os.remove(image_url) # Remove the cached file
  axis[i].imshow(img)

  img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
  prediction_scores = model.predict(np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)/255)
  axis[i].title.set_text(np.argmax(prediction_scores, axis=1))
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see, the predictions are perfect, the last image belong to class 0 (empty squash court) and the second image belong to class 1 (players playing in squash court)

Comment: Great, thanks! Would never have thought that keras was cacheing the image downloads.

I updated my colab notebook and it working correctly. However, when I save the trained model and then try to use it in another script then the predictions are totally wrong.  

To save the model I just did: 

`tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_path)`

Then in my new script I do: `model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./saved_flowers_model/')`

But the new script predictions are totally wrong using the same code you shared above.

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of doing keras.... I had to call everything with tf.keras... I suppose just using keras directly causes some version conflict with tf.keras .